# Should exceptions be defined in use cases?

Tags: project-management, use-case

Say you have a use case called 'schedule meeting.' Defined in the spec, meetings can only be scheduled for the current time or the future. In the Use Case should it include the flow where "if the date/time given is in the past, a message box will show 'meeting time cannot be in the past'"?

Like I said, it's defined in the spec that the date/time cannot be in the past, but in the use case definition, should it be defined there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The business work flows should not be technical if they can be avoided.

Saying something like 'The User shall see an Error under these conditions..." is ok, but it is up to the developers to define how to implement that.  Exceptions might be a good way, but the business stake holders should be indifferent to the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad that I found this old thread!  I've just read the wiki entry for use-case exceptions, and it threw up some problems for me.

Let me just say that, as I understand a use case to be properly used, you should not make a past-date meeting an exception.

A use case expresses a requirement, in this case, to schedule a meeting. Dealing with invalid meeting requests actually is a part of the scheduling process, and not an exception to it.

The requirement exists, without exception, as does the use case. Invalid dates are a detail item. Think of your use case as a more general, table of contents.

If you are modelling iteratively, you will 'discover' and manage the requirement to reject invalid meeting requests, as you elaborate your model/document.

,

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that I found this old thread!  I've just read the wiki entry for use-case exceptions, and it threw up some problems for me.

Let me just say that, as I understand a use case to be properly used, you should not make a past-date meeting an exception.

A use case expresses a requirement, in this case, to schedule a meeting. Dealing with invalid meeting requests actually is a part of the scheduling process, and not an exception to it.

The requirement exists, without exception, as does the use case. Invalid dates are a detail item. Think of your use case as a more general, table of contents.

If you are modelling iteratively, you will 'discover' and manage the requirement to reject invalid meeting requests, as you elaborate your model/document.

Put even more succinctly, you have described a schedule meeting function. A UML use case should not be used for functional-driven development.

Comment: Don't post a new answer for that. Edit your existing answer if you have to add something.